# img not functioning as block with display: block in the way I imagined

Tags: html, css

I'm new. I'm doing a project and I'm trying my best to understand floats and the way they interact with other things etc. I've learned a lot but something has me stumped. I made a simple practice pen so I could test things out without messing with my main project. My main question has to do with the way img is interacting with the left float. Instead of going under it, like the div red box did in my experiment, it goes to the right of it. I considered that because the img is inline like text, it's trying to wrap around the box like I've seen before. I thought maybe img would interact with floats similarly to text. In normal document flow, if I have the red box above the blue box, and then i float the red box left, the blue box will go under the red box like any block element should. If I try that with an img under the red box, the img will just go to the right of the red box. This doesn't surprise me since the img is inline. What I don't understand is that when I display the img as block, it functions the same exact way with no changes. If I display it as block, shouldn't it work as a block in the same way the blue box works as a block, and go under and be covered by the floating left red box? 
Also, I've tried that without putting the img in a div container. I thought that by putting the img in a div, it might function as a block via the div, but that wasn't working for me either. I assume it's because of some kind of positioning I need on both the div and the img. I know there are a few questions here but if anyone could help me understand this it would be great. Thank you.

```
.redbox { background-color: red; height: 200px; width: 200px;float: right} .bluebox { background-color: blue; height: 200px; width: 200px; float: left;} .greenbox { background-color: green; height: 200px; width: 200px;}.divpadding { padding: 20px; background: yellow; } img {display: block;}
```

https://codepen.io/WitlessMean/pen/QWwpgYj?editors=1100

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: RE: control k --- / unless I don't know your system - I'm betting it's `control+v`. You can also give us the link to the codepen...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

I can see that you've thought about this a lot and that you have a lot of enthusiasm, but - we can't really follow! : )

Here's some tips to help you get the best answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Here are some notes about your question:
https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/f47ox32g/

...

This is pretty much the only reason you'll ever want to use floats - post-flex-box. The way I choose to think of it... is not that they image 'floats left' - but that it allows the other content to float *around* it. Does this help? To be clear... I haven't used a float in years... So - maybe it's not the right tool for you?

```css
.example-area {
  max-width: 300px; /* to prove the point */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.example-area img {
  float: left; /* let things float around it... */
  margin-right: 10px; /* just to give it some space */
}

.example-area p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="example-area">

  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x80" />

  <p>Example text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam ex blanditiis esse iure doloribus perspiciatis ipsum necessitatibus earum officia error iste cupiditate, nihil consequatur dolorum incidunt nisi molestias modi!</p>
  
</section>
```